# Adding a new field to Model with Database-First Approach MVC3 does not pull data from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, database-first

I'm trying to add a new field to an existing database (MS SQL Server) and MVC 3 model using the database-first approach. The database and model structure is very complex and the DB hold lots of data, so it is not an option to drop the database and rebuild it. So far I've tried the following to no avail:

1. Added the field into the database first and then went into the .edmx file. I clicked the table and selected "Update Model from Database"

   - This adds the field into the model, but the data is not pulled from the database. I checked this by breaking during debugging and checking the model list. It just gives the field the default value from the model.
2. Added the field in the model first and then added the field to the database (with script below).

   - This creates a second model variable with "_1" and maps it to the database field.

#### Code Reference

The script for adding the field into the database table:

> > `ALTER TABLE stores`
> >     `ADD active bit NOT NULL DEFAULT 1`

The code for the model that is added in:

> > `public bool active { get; set; }`

The code for populating the list of stores:

> > `var storeList = (from n in db.stores select n).ToList();`

**How do I get it to work where the model field will be populated by the data from the database and not by the model default value?**

Answer (score 0):

In a situation like this, you may need to delete and subsequently recreate your Entity Model using the wizard.

Comment: Do I delete the edmx file and the .tt files?

Comment: @mvc_tyro If you delete the `.edmx`, it should also delete the `.tt` files. Visual Studio should group them together as one piece of the project.

Comment: No, VS does not delete the .tt files for you. It has to be deleted manually.

Comment: @mvc_tyro I've never had that issue, but go ahead and do that, then recreate the model. If it works, mark this as the correct answer.